# Are database calls in cloud functions counted as regular request?

Tags: parse-platform

As per FAQs of parse.com,

***How are requests made from Cloud Code treated under the request limit?***

*Calling a Cloud function will count itself as a single request. Save and delete triggers in Cloud Code are considered part of the original object save/delete request, and they will not be counted as an additional request. **However, if your function or save/delete trigger uses the Parse JavaScript SDK to perform additional operations, these will be treated in the same way they would as if they were made by a regular client.***

What does using JS sdk in cloud code exactly mean? If i make simple database call like *query.find* from a cloud function or trigger then will that be counted as regular client request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes `query.find` will be a database request. Any query execution wil be.